# Need help to boot Ubuntu after Failing to mount EFI

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, mount, uefi

Last week I managed to crash my Windows fataly and I had to reinstall it. Obviously that meant that my Grub disappeard afterwards and I did my job using Boot-Repair to get it back. Since then I noticed that several new options where in the grub boot menu: Mokmanager.efi, fwupx64.efi etc...

When I try to enter Ubuntu now it failes to mount to them and I am directed into the maintenance prompt. Can someone help me to figure out what to do? I could try unmount the failing paths but I am concerned about destroying it even more. I hope you guys can help me out of this without reinstalling everything again.

Thank you all in advance and please let me know what informations exactly you need from me!

Edit:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   128M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0 736.1G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0  18.6G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda4   8:4    0  18.6G  0 part /media/ubuntu/b918a6c9-6a8d-4a76-a61c-bf1eacd296a1
└─sda5   8:5    0 158.1G  0 part /media/ubuntu/33735948-3223-45af-8d0f-9ffbe578305c
sdb      8:16   0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   450M  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0   100M  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   0    16M  0 part 
└─sdb4   8:20   0 237.9G  0 part 
sdc      8:32   1   7.5G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   1   7.5G  0 part /cdrom
loop0    7:0    0   1.4G  1 loop /rofs
```

Here is the content of `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`:
[Link](https://pastebin.com/embed_js/S1q4RriX)

Here is the link to the bootinfoscript output: [Link](https://pastebin.com/M7Rz1xaG)

Edit 2:

Okay so I deleted the contents of my fstab file wich caused some weird errors because of the uefi mounts boot-repair tried to setup. But I got a new problem now. My ubuntu lacks its visual representation and I only have a terminal window now.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! The output of `lsblk` along with the content of `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` would be useful to [edit] into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Related Possible Duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/286108/failed-to-mount-boot-efi?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to mount /boot/efi](http://askubuntu.com/questions/286108/failed-to-mount-boot-efi)

Comment: Okay i will edit it thank you. I took a look at those posts but as I said already I am not quiet sure and that is what bothers me risking my os :s

Comment: Risk can be managed by insuring that you have a [complete backup.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc/586172#586172) That's the approach I use to allow me the freedom to try whatever I want without concern. I highly recommend it.

Comment: Whats the easiest way to post the file contents here only using this repair prompt? :oo

Comment: Boot from [live media](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install)

Comment: I tried to add the contents of grub.cfg but the line limit prevents me from doing it x.x

Comment: IF all else fails provide a link to a [pastie](https://pastebin.com/)

Comment: Did it .. Hope it is helpful.

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: I will run it as soon as I am back home. Thank you all again for your efforts.

Comment: Okay added the output of the boot info script. Thank you!

Comment: What version of Windows did you have? And what did you reinstall? It looks like you may have converted from BIOS to UEFI as now both drives are gpt. Windows only boots in UEFI mode from gpt drives. How you boot install media for both Windows & Ubuntu UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs. You have to always be consistent.

Comment: I have and had Windows 10 before :) hmm okay :o how will I be able to get Ubuntu back? As I said I only used boot repair default settings :)

Comment: Can anyone help? I am sorry for being annoying but it's really important to me^^

Comment: Please use a newer boot-repair script and rerun.  Look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I used the newest one... I reinstalled ubuntu now.. hope it doesn't break again.