# Error processing package shim-signed

Tags: apt, grub-efi

I just run an apt-get upgrade on my Ubuntu 16.04 installation and I am getting this error:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up shim-signed (1.32~16.04.1+0.9+1474479173.6c180c6-1ubuntu1) ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: /boot/efi doesn't look like an EFI partition.
.
dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 shim-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The output of `df -h` is

```
polesemi@pcsensori34:~$ df -h
Filesystem                                          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                                7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                               1,6G  9,5M  1,6G   1% /run
/dev/sdb1                                           213G  135G   68G  67% /
tmpfs                                               7,8G  316M  7,5G   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                               5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                                               7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
polesemi@login.dei.unipd.it:/home/polesemi          5,7T  2,1T  3,6T  37% /home/polesemi/homeDei
polesemi@login.dei.unipd.it:/nfsd/signet/ns/polese  475G  266G  210G  56% /home/polesemi/nsDei
tmpfs                                               1,6G  108K  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

The output of `parted` is

```
polesemi@pcsensori34:~$ sudo parted -l
[sudo] password for polesemi: 
Model: ATA ST500DM002-1SB10 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      32,3kB  41,1MB  41,1MB  primary  fat16        diag
 2      41,9MB  12,6GB  12,6GB  primary  ntfs         boot, diag
 3      12,6GB  500GB   487GB   primary  ntfs


Model: ATA KINGSTON SHSS37A (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 240GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name  Flags
 3      1049kB  212MB  211MB   fat32           efi   boot, esp
 1      212MB   232GB  232GB   ext4
 2      232GB   240GB  8000MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

What can I do to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: There may be some help in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286108/failed-to-mount-boot-efi/286288#286288)

Comment: It appears that my /boot/efi folder is not empty

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of these two commands: `df -h` and `sudo parted -l`. (That's a lowercase `-L`, not a numeric `-1`.) Post a comment so that I notice your new information.

Comment: Hi Rod, I added the output of those commands.

Comment: This issue is still present as of today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shim-signed/+bug/1736080
Basically, the /boot/efi partition was not mounted correctly (UUID mismatch in the /etc/fstab file). Once I managed to mount it, the package installed correctly.

Comment: What if I don't have /boot/efi in my fstab because my system is not installed in UEFI mode?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to help, Mark

It just happened to me, and the issue was my partitions were "Commented Out" in /etc/fstab.

To check run

```
cat /etc/fstab
```

I opened GParted to confirm the UUIDs for their partitions and all were right. Then I "Uncommented Out" all the partitions, and yes they were ALL commented out?  Weird!!  Restarted Ubuntu, updated/upgraded and the error left.

The command was

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

and to re-iterate for newbies - "Uncommenting Out" means - Take out the the '#' (number signs) in front of the UUID Lines
ex

> ****#****UUID=92a37016-1b32-4743-973e-e792bb3c48ca /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
>   to read
>
> UUID=92a37016-1b32-4743-973e-e792bb3c48ca /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

I hope this helps, Mark