# Terminal crash during apt-upgrade on ubuntu and now upgrade fails

Tags: upgrade, grub-efi

I was upgrading Ubuntu using

```
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

But, the terminal crashed in between. When I tried to run the same command again, it gave an error related to lock on dpkg. I deleted the lock files.
Now when I run the command, I get the following error

```
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up shim-signed (1.33.1~16.04.3+15+1533136590.3beb971-0ubuntu1) ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 shim-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am not sure what is wrong here. Can somebody help me here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error processing package shim-signed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948315/error-processing-package-shim-signed)

Comment: Take a look at this similar question/answer: [Error processing package shim signed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948315/error-processing-package-shim-signed)