# Failed to boot after restore with Timeshift

Tags: grub2, boot-repair, timeshift

First of all, I want to state that I looked for similar answers to my problem and it did not work in my case, including here [Failed to mount /boot/efi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286108/failed-to-mount-boot-efi)

Here are my system details with desk version: Ubuntu 20.04.4 installed on NUC gen 10 with m2-nvme. No windows, only Ubuntu.

My version of Ubuntu was 20.04.1 LTS and I made a backup with Timeshift (on the mounted SSD, called sda) before upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. The upgrade went OK.

But in 20.4.4 with php 8, I had problems with the website. I also made a backup here with Timeshift (on the mounted SSD, called sda).
After that I decided to restore to the backup from ubuntu 20.04.01. After initializing the restore procedure with Timeshift, I noticed that I had no feedback with "Restore complete" or something like that, and I left the PC on for 1 hour.
On restart I noticed the error: **Failed to mount /boot/efi**, plus hundreds of other errors.
Then I used Ubuntu live image and I used **boot-repair** which gave me positive feedback that is repaired.
But on restart it didn't boot.
The error is :

```
[UNSUPP] Starting of Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point unsupported
```

More details here: https://prnt.sc/Fi9vfFMG7UG2

I tried to start the mysql service but it was not possible. I can attach some print screens if needed with what it looks now after trying to boot

LE: Console after boot. https://prnt.sc/NytlEHJ8KUhr

Now my goal is to recover at least the MYSQL database.

Here is the log generated by boot-repair https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/JrwcsnnSpq/

Comment: If it does not boot, how could you try to start the database?

Comment: Is not booting in Ubuntu, its stoped to console. Check prints.